# How to create a UIImage RGB gradient with a portion of black programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm wanting to generate a UIImage that's a RGB gradient that also has a portion of black on the left side. I would like to do this programmatically, instead of having to make the image in Photoshop and using it as an asset in the app.

I've searched on here and have seen the generation of iOS color wheels before, but nothing like a rectangle below which I mocked in Photoshop:

This will be for letting users change text color as they touch inside of the UIImage.

I'm not really sure where to begin however, and would appreciate some pointers.

[image: color]

Comment: http://krazydad.com/tutorials/makecolors.php this could be helpful

Comment: That's javascript, not Objective-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code creates a gradient [from red,yellow,green,blue,red]  and returns RGB values if touched on it.
The below code can be used for any number of colors, just set their value in colors Array.
The selected color is set as backgroundColor for selectedColorView(UIView).

ViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

ViewController.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController{
    UIView *selectedColorView;
    CAGradientLayer *layer;
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    layer =[CAGradientLayer layer];
    [layer setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 50)];
    layer.colors =@[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    layer.startPoint =CGPointMake(0, .5);
    layer.endPoint =CGPointMake(1, .5);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

    selectedColorView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20+50, 280, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:selectedColorView];

}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint p = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(layer.frame, p)){
        CGFloat xOffset = (p.x - layer.frame.origin.x);
        CGFloat gap=(layer.frame.size.width/(layer.colors.count-1));
        NSInteger index = xOffset/gap;
        xOffset =xOffset -index*gap;

        UIColor *color1=[UIColor colorWithCGColor:(CGColorRef)layer.colors[index]];
        UIColor *color2=[UIColor colorWithCGColor:(CGColorRef)layer.colors[index+1]];
        CGFloat r1,g1,b1,a1,r2,g2,b2,a2;
        [color1 getRed:&r1 green:&g1 blue:&b1 alpha:&a1];
        [color2 getRed:&r2 green:&g2 blue:&b2 alpha:&a2];

        selectedColorView.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:(1-(xOffset/gap))*r1 +(xOffset/gap)*r2 green:(1-(xOffset/gap))*g1 +(xOffset/gap)*g2 blue:(1-(xOffset/gap))*b1 +(xOffset/gap)*b2 alpha:1.0];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Wow, amazing code, I didn't expect for you to provide so much help. Quick question before I accept this answer: How can I make the transitions between each UIColor more smooth? As they are quite abrupt and unpleasing at the moment. Thanks again!

Comment: What I mean is you can clearly see where each UIColor ends and starts, I'd like to smooth them out so it looks like the image in my question above.

Comment: Apple opened just colours for us and the rest of chemistry is with them.And more over the gradient generated is the exact gradient.Try lowering the amount of intensities for colors, like for green color instead of setting 1.0f set .8f, then it looks smoothened.

Comment: Is there anyway I can create an RGB rectangle using a bezier path instead using the Hue Saturation Brightness model?

Answer (score 0):

i think you could draw a gradient color on a context and then create a image of this context.

or maybe you can also do it like this.
http://belencruz.com/2012/12/gradient-background-in-ios-without-images/

Comment: That's only for two UIColors, how could I create a for loop to fill in the remaining spectrum?

Comment: Edit: a for loop would be rediculous to be do doing all the permutations of the RGB spectrum.